# Правильная структура приложения на NestJS

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

Создаю приложения для мониторинга посещений студентов и педагогов.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Создал модуль `student`. В нём контроллер и сервис для работы со студентами. В нём есть `entities`: `student` и `visit`. Эти две сущности связаны друг с другом. Появилась необходимость создать сущности `teacher` и `grade` (учителя и классы). Я считаю, что для них стоит сделать сделать отдельные модули (в том числе для `visit`) и в них добавлять эти сущности. Но я не знаю как правильно тогда делать отношения между ними. Писать огромные пути для импорта? Есть какие-то иные способы?

Нынешний код:

```
import { Visit } from 'src/visit/models/visit.entity';
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';


@Entity('students')
export class Student {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: Date })
  birthday: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Visit, (visit) => visit.student)
  visits: Visit[];
}
```

visit.entity.ts

```
import { Student } from 'src/student/models/student.entity';
import { Column, Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('visits')
export class Visit {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: Date })
  date: Date;

  @ManyToOne(() => Student, (student) => student.visits)
  student: Student;
}
```

---

Спасибо за ответ Alexander Yukal. Перестроил приложение таким образом

```
├── src
│   ├── app.controller.spec.ts
│   ├── app.controller.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── app.service.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── modules
│       ├── group
│       │   ├── group.controller.ts
│       │   ├── group.module.ts
│       │   ├── group.service.ts
│       │   └── models
│       │       └── group.entity.ts
│       ├── type
│       │   ├── models
│       │   │   └── type.entity.ts
│       │   ├── type.controller.ts
│       │   ├── type.module.ts
│       │   └── type.service.ts
│       ├── visit
│       │   ├── models
│       │   │   └── visit.entity.ts
│       │   ├── visit.controller.ts
│       │   ├── visit.module.ts
│       │   └── visit.service.ts
│       └── visitor
│           ├── dto
│           │   └── visitor.dto.ts
│           ├── models
│           │   └── visitor.entity.ts
│           ├── visitor.controller.ts
│           ├── visitor.module.ts
│           └── visitor.service.ts
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В целом я вижу у вас есть изначально проблемы с построением структуры приложения.

> Создал модуль `student`. В нём контроллер и сервис для работы со студентами. В нём есть entities: `student` и `visit`.

Во первых, вникая в описание, создается впечатление некой вложенности всего и вся в одном файле, что по сути говорит о природе вашего приложения, которое не имеет архитектурной структуры (слоев) приложения.

В любом случае, если вы придерживаетесь какого-нибудь паттерна ([MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), [CQRS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CQRS)) или что-то иное (а `Nest.js` как раз тот фреймворк, который несет в себе философию именно такого архитектурного подхода: [MVC](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) / [CQRS](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs)), вы должны понимать что суть данных  паттернов, это суть разделение на зоны ответственности, поведения и т.п. Поэтому в модели не должно быть никакой реализации бизнес-логики кроме описания структуры таблицы БД, где каждая таблица это отдельный `js-файл`.

Отношения между [модулями](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) может осуществляться с помощью экспорта и импорта, это есть в [документации](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting).

#### Структура

Вариант 1:

Если представить старую заезжую до дыр MVC модель с её структурой, от которой у бывалых разработчиков начинается нервный тик (подробно [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/204958/) и [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/321050/)), то структура будет выглядеть так:

```
src
├─ models
│  ├─ model.student.ts
│  ├─ model.visit.ts
│  ├─ model.teacher.ts
│  ├─ model.grade.ts
│  └─ ...
├─ controllers
│  ├─ controller.student.ts
│  ├─ controller.teacher.ts
│  └─ ...
├─ views
│  └─ ...
│
├─ package.json
└─ main.ts
```

Но, так как построение архитектуры `Nest.js` в значительной степени была вдохновением `​​Angular`, о чем они честно признаются и пишут об этом в документации, механизм немного имзенился и к привычному контроллеру был добавлен `service`, суть которого реализация основного кода бизнес логики. Основная же суть контроллера состоит в том чтобы принимать роут-запросы и делегировать процессы сервису. По задумке авторов фреймворка контроллер должен содержать минимальную реализацию бизнес логики. Именно поэтому `MVC` модель здесь никак не вписывается в архитектуру приложения, так как у нас есть два разделения ответственности: `controllers` и `services`. В следствии этого смотрим следующий вариант:

Вариант 2:

```
src
├─ entities
│  ├─ student.ts
│  ├─ visit.ts
│  ├─ teacher.ts
│  ├─ grade.ts
│  └─ ...
│
├─ realization
│  ├─ students
│  │  ├─ student.service.ts
│  │  └─ student.controller.ts
│  ├─ teachers
│  │  ├─ teacher.service.ts
│  │  └─ teacher.controller.ts
│  └─ ...
│
├─ tests
│  ├─ integration
│  │  ├─ test.teacher.ts
│  │  ├─ test.student.ts
│  │  └─ ...
│  ├─ e2e
│  │  └─ ...
│  └─ graphql
│     └─ ...
│
├─ user.module.ts
├─ document.module.ts
├─ ...
├─ package.json
└─ main.ts
```

В данном примере был исключен фактор представления `views`, так как это  индивидуальный фактор зависящий от особенности проекта (микросервисы, предсавление также может обрабатываться другими фрейморками, такими как `Vuejs`, `React`, `Angular`). Здесь уже есть директория `realization` которая вмещает в себе и контроллер и сервис, что характерно для данной задумке архитектуры. Название `realization` было выбрано для демонстрации, его можно переименовать по своему усмотрению. А также было добавлено два компонента: `user` и `document`, где `user` это сущность `student` или `teacher`, а `document` соответственно что-то иное.

В целом ваша структура может быть какой угодно включая вложенность директорий и файлов. Команда разработчиков также любезно предоставила множество [примеров](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample) того как может быть организована структура архитектуры приложения на `Nest.js`. А именно [вот здесь](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/01-cats-app) находится пример, который описан в документации `Nest.js`, где сущность `cats` есть нечто иное как сущность предметной области.

#### Модуль

Суть [модуля](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) это объединение контроллера и сервиса (возможно нескольких) в один единый полноценный компонент, который является частью всего приложения. С помощью модулей, используя импорт / экспорт, вы можете связать реализацию других компонентов.

Подводя итог, в дополнение советую вам ознакомиться с такими терминами как:

- [чистая архитектура](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0&oq=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i65l2.276j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- [Предметно-ориентированное проектирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) или оригинал: [Domain Driven Design](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainDrivenDesign.html)

Также советую посмотреть этот [видео-доклад](https://youtu.be/MYXt_9d_2ps).

На самом деле тема правильной структуры приложения, как и структуры приложения в целом, это довольно сложная тема которая может иметь множество абсолютно разных решений и как правило несет за собой очень много нераскрытых подтем и кусков кода, что сложно уместить в формате `StackOverflow`, философия которого лежит в основе быстрого ответа / решения. Но я постарался немного приоткрыть занавес и оставил вам немного ссылок для ознакомления :)